# split a string into and manipulate it in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I will have to do arithmetic operation from the below string by using VBscript.

```
s = "1+2-3+4"
```

output => 4

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBScript, use the **[eval method](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_eval.asp)**

Example

```
total = Eval("1+2-3+4")
```

Excel VBA, use evaluate method
Example

```
total = Evaluate("1+2-3+4")
```

Comment: Works fine, Thanks.

Comment: @NMKP if it works fine... why havent you accepted his answer?  I little rude, if you ask me.